# Swift Package Manager dependency in a repository subdirectory

Tags: swift, github, swift-package-manager

I have a Swift package in a subdirectory of a git repository inside GitHub. The tree looks something like this:

```
.
├── swift-package
│   ├── Package.swift
│   └── Sources
│       └── SomeLibrary
│           └── Library.swift
└── some-other-files
```

I want to add `swift-package` as a dependency to another project.

But the only way of [specifying a dependency](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/master/Documentation/PackageDescription.md) using Swift Package Manager I know is when the package is at the top level of the repository:

```
dependencies: [
    .package(url: "http://github.com/Some/Repository", from: "1.2.3"),
],
```

What I would need would be something along the lines of `.package(url: "http://github.com/Some/Repository, dir: "swift-package"...)`.

I have no way of moving out the package to a separate repository.

Is there any way to achieve something like this using Swift Package Manager? If not, what are my options? Also, what is the best way to submit a feature request to Swift Package Manger developers?

Comment: For anyone encountering this in the future, note that you can't have multiple **packages**, but you can have multiple **targets** and **products** which can specify paths relative to the top-level Package.swift, and have dependencies. See https://swift.org/package-manager/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can not have two Swift packages in the same git repository. The [Swift Package manager defines a package](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/main/Documentation/Usage.md#creating-a-package) as:

> Packages are Git repositories, tagged with semantic versions, containing a Package.swift file at their root. Initializing the
> package created a Package.swift file, but to make it a usable package
> we need to initialize a Git repository with at least one version tag.

Your options are to either have separate repositories/packages for your dependencies, or use one repository and move the code in separate modules/targets.

If you need to submit a feature I would first start a discussion in the [Swift forums](https://forums.swift.org/c/development/SwiftPM) describing your goals and requesting feedback from the community. The code for the Swift PM is hosted in [github](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager) you can always submit a pull request with a new feature. More information about the process is [described here](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager#contributions).

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly the proper answer, but I wonder if, as a workaround, we could add the corresponding repo as [Git submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules), and then integrate the package as a *local* package from the corresponding subdirectory. We would lose the ability to update (or change the version of) the package via SPM, though. On the other hand, we would still be able to control the version of the package, by pinning the Git submodule to version tags (or branches/commits/whatever), that should be there in Git repository anyway for SPM, if I recall it correctly.